# DIscord.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an issue with my code.

```
if (command === 'channel'){
    if (args.length == 0 ){
        return message.channel.send(Aucun argument trouvé)
    }
    await message.guild.channels
    .create(args[0] ,{
        type : 'text' ,
    })

    .then((chan)=>{
    var data = fs.readFileSync('test.json')
    var parsedata = JSON.parse(data)



    var test = 0
    console.log(parsedata['category'])

    try {
        chan.setParent( parsedata['category'])
    }catch{

        message.channel.send("il s'emblerais que la commande category est mal été configuré ")
        channel.delete()
        console.log("end")
        return

    }


    });
    message.channel.send("channel "+args[0]+" crée :)")

};
```

I'm trying to create a channel and move it to a category. The category ID is stored in a file called `test.json`.

My problem is if the ID stored does not exist then the try-catch should stop the error and execute the code in the `catch` block.
but that is not the case.

Here is the error:

```
node:15548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
parent_id: Category does not exist
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\etoile\Desktop\ts bot js\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (c:\Users\etoile\Desktop\ts bot js\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async TextChannel.edit (c:\Users\etoile\Desktop\ts bot js\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildChannel.js:355:21)
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
<node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:42
(node:15548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
<node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:42
(node:15548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thank for your help in advance

Comment: It looks like the category with the id == `parsedata['category']` does not exists.
What does `parsedata['category']` return? Can you show structure of `test.json`?

Comment: Actually the ```parsedata['category']``` is set buy a user so want to check if the category is existing and im in the case where the id set does not exist .I want the try catch to get the error . And my test.json is very simple and look llike that 
```
{
  "category": "6541651651"
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error as the parent category doesn't exist. If you want to catch this error, you'll need to use the `await` keyword in front of `chan.setParent()` (as the [`.setParent()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setParent) method is asynchronous):

```js
if (command === 'channel') {
  if (args.length === 0) return message.channel.send('Aucun argument trouvé');

  try {
    let chan = await message.guild.channels.create(args[0], {
      type: 'text',
    });

    let data = fs.readFileSync('test.json');
    let parsedata = JSON.parse(data);

    await chan.setParent(parsedata['category']);

    message.channel.send(`channel ${args[0]} crée :)`);
  } catch {
    message.channel.send(
      "il s'emblerais que la commande category est mal été configuré",
    );
    // not sure what channel you want to delete here
    channel.delete();
  }
}
```